# Following this simple pybind11 tutorial gives "ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function"

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I'm following [this short tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5T70cAXDJ0) for building a python module from c++ code.

I have this cpp file

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

float some_fn(float arg1, float arg2)
{
    return arg1 + arg2;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(module_name, handle)
{
    handle.doc() = "This is the module docs.";
    handle.def("some_fn_py", &some_fn, "some fn");
}
```

and this cmake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(pybind_test)
add_subdirectory(pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(pybind_test main.cpp)
```

The module is produced, but when I try to import it in a python script

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'.'))

import pybind_test
```

I get the error

```
"ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_pybind_test)"
```

I am not sure why.

Comment: The "module_name" argument to `PYBIND11_MODULE` should be your module name. If you are building a module named `pybind_test`, use `PYBIND11_MODULE(pybind_test, handle)`.

Comment: This change worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did not properly pass the module name to PYBIND11_MODULE. Here is the working version

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

float some_fn(float arg1, float arg2)
{
    return arg1 + arg2;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(pybind_test, handle)
{
    handle.doc() = "This is the module docs.";
    handle.def("some_fn_py", &some_fn, "some fn");
}
```